# PHP oop how to call another class method in a easier way?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am new to php OOP. I have a question regarding my situation.

**db.php**

```
class db{

protected $db_host;
protected $db_name;
protected $db_user_name;
protected $db_pass;

public function __construct() {
    $this->db_host="localhost";
    $this->db_name="bs";
    $this->db_user_name="root";
    $this->db_pass="";
}

public function conn(){

    try {   
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user_name="root", $this->db_pass);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $conn;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**item.php**

```
require "../../includes/db.php";

class item{

public $user_uid;
public $last_id;
public $display_item;
public $iid;

protected $item_id;
protected $item_name;
protected $item_price;
protected $item_quantity;

public function add_item($uid,$item_id,$item_n,$item_p,$item_q){

    $db = new db();
    $conn=$db->conn();

    $this->user_uid=$uid;
    $this->item_id=$item_id;
    $this->item_name=$item_n;
    $this->item_price=$item_p;
    $this->item_quantity=$item_q;

    try {
        $sql = "INSERT item(uid,item_id,item_name,item_price,item_quantity) 
                    VALUES('$this->user_uid','$this->item_id','$this->item_name','$this->item_price','$this->item_quantity')";
        $conn->exec($sql);
        $this->last_id=$conn->lastInsertId();
    }

    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
}

public function display_item($uid){

    $db = new db();
    $conn=$db->conn();

    $this->user_uid=$uid;

    try{

        $sql="SELECT * FROM item where uid='$this->user_uid'";
        $statement=$conn->query($sql);

        while($row=$statement->fetch()){

            $this->iid[]=$row['iid'];
            $this->display_item[]=[$row['item_id'],$row['item_name'],$row['item_price'],$row['item_quantity']];

        }

    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
}
}
```

as you can see from item.php , i have to call

```
$db = new db();
$conn=$db->conn();
```

in add_item() and display_item() .

So that means every method that I have to access to database connection, i have to do that. Is there a easier way to do that by not creating $db = new db() in other class by modifying my codes?

OR

Did i miss out some functions that PHP can do that?

**My desired way of doing it**

```
require "../../includes/db.php";
$db = new db();
$conn=$db->conn();

class item{

...
...

public function add_item($uid,$item_id,$item_n,$item_p,$item_q){
try {
    $sql = "INSERT item(uid,item_id,item_name,item_price,item_quantity) 
                VALUES('$this->user_uid','$this->item_id','$this->item_name','$this->item_price','$this->item_quantity')";
    $conn->exec($sql);
}

public function display_item($uid){

....

try{

        $sql="SELECT * FROM item where uid='$this->user_uid'";
        $statement=$conn->query($sql);
```

so that i only declare 1 time()

```
$db = new db();
$conn=$db->conn();
```

in class item() and use it for the rest of methods.

Comment: just add conn in the properties, inside the constructor connect from there

Comment: @Ghost hi ghost, nice to hear from your reply again. can show me an example? I just need a simple example will do!

Comment: I'd recommend maybe looking into a dependency injection container solution such as Pimple; http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/ or http://php-di.org/

Comment: @Perspective hmm.. I dont think my question is that complicated such as I have to install some program? correct me if i am wrong. thx

Comment: You're correct it's not, and it does have a learning curve, but it could be something good to learn as best practice. Here is a bit more context as to why I even mentioned it as a possible solution; http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the connection in the constructor. Add the necessary property as well:

```
class db
{

    protected $db_host;
    protected $db_name;
    protected $db_user_name;
    protected $db_pass;
    protected $db_conn; // add me here
```

Then inside the constructor, use the credentials there to connect. So that when you create the object, its already connected, you'll just use the property connection for your executing queries and stuff:

```
public function __construct() 
{
    $this->db_host = "localhost";
    $this->db_name = "bs";
    $this->db_user_name = "root";
    $this->db_pass = "";

    // connect
    try {   
        $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user_name="root", $this->db_pass);
        $this->db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Then, extend the `db` class in item. You can now use `db`'s `db_conn` property inside `item` class.

```
class item extends db
{

    public $user_uid;
    public $last_id;
    public $display_item;
    public $iid;

    protected $item_id;
    protected $item_name;
    protected $item_price;
    protected $item_quantity;


    public function display_item($uid)
    {
        try {

            $stmt = $this->db_conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM item WHERE uid = :uid');
            $stmt->bindValue(':uid', $uid);
            $stmt->execute();

            foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
                $this->iid[] = $row['iid'];
                $this->display_item[] = [$row['item_id'], $row['item_name'], $row['item_price'], $row['item_quantity']];
            }

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Sidenote: I've added prepared statements on top

Comment: I think my question not clear enough. I got error when doing your way . I have added more info and the desired way of doing it. please have a look. thx

Comment: @gosulove it was too long of a post to provide the complete answer a while ago, i had to finish it inside using a proper text editor, i've edited it above